# How to pass props to React Picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a picker from `react-native-picker-select`. I also have button where if I press it, I want to pass props to the picker and have it displayed as the label.

I've tried setting a `callback` function from the button, passing the props to the picker with the label being set as the props. I can see the props being passed but the picker is not updating.

**Score.js**

```
<View style={styles.button}>
  <TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.scoreButton}
         onPress={() => this.props.pressMe()}>
         <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Press</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

**Main.js**

```
pressMe = () => {
    if (this.state.level== 1) {
      this.setState({ scoreInput: 100 });
    }
  };

<Deadlift
   scoreInput={this.state.scoreInput}/>

<View style={styles.scoreContainer}>
   <Score
      pressMe={this.pressMe} />
</View>
```

**Deadlift.js**

```
 var picker = (<Picker
          {...this.props}
          style={pickerSelectStyles}
          placeholder={{
            label: 'Weight',
            value: null,
          }}
          items={this.state.items}
          onValueChange={value => {
            onDLHandler(value, this.getScore(value));
          }}
          value={this.props.scoreInput} <- outside of picker shows this is 
                          logged as 100 but value is not being updated on picker
        />)

<View>{picker}</View>
```

Comment: where is your scoreOutput component

Comment: Just updated it

Comment: change ```pressMe={this.pressMe}``` to ```pressMe={(value) => this.pressMe(value)}``` in main.js and remove {...this.props}  and add ```onValueChange={(value) => this.props. pressMe(value)}``` in scoreOutput.js

Comment: that didn't work. plus, i'm not passing pressMe directly to scoreOutput. i'm passing it to main.js and then passing scoreInput props to scoreOutput.

Comment: @fosho where were your scoreOutput component used in the main or somewhere? I only see scoreInput

Comment: @Lenoarod I guess I should use proper naming in these examples I'm showing...sorry about that. scoreOutput component is Deadlift component in main.js

Comment: what does this `items={this.state.items}` refer to? it's better if you can post entire Deadlift component here

Comment: @Max items is a picker element and this.state.items is an array of a hundred numbers

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/blob/master/README.md#props) of "value" props

> Will attempt to locate a matching item from the items array by
>   checking each item's value property. If found, it will update the
>   component to show that item as selected. If the value is not found, it
>   will default to the first item.

**The picker does not find the object "{ scoreInput: 100 }" in items array so picker does not update . You have to add in items array also if you want to update the picker**

Comment: this is what i figured out on the docs. have to pass the items array to where i'm setting the state, then push the state to the array, then pass the item array back to the picker.

Answer (score 0):

As the doc states, items should be an array of objects with label and value keys, not just an array of values

https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/blob/master/README.md#props

Comment: thanks, i'm using like that.

my picker works fine normally. just not how i described in my original question.